# /proc not mounted as expected inside chroot?

Tags: linux, ls, chroot, proc, root-filesystem

I set `chroot` for my project folder `~/workspace/apollo.0` to create a security JAIL.

After running `chroot` command, fake root filesystem is created in my project folder to make it as security JAIL.

To analyse each sub-folder in my project folder,

**Case 1:** **By exiting** from `chroot` ran below commands,

```
overexchange@ab111@~/workspace/apollo.0>mountpoint /proc; printf "$?\n"
/proc is a mountpoint
0
overexchange@ab111@~/workspace/apollo.0>mountpoint proc/; printf "$?\n"
proc/ is not a mountpoint
1
overexchange@ab111@~/workspace/apollo.0>
```

As I exit from `chroot`, `/proc` is `proc` in actual root file system. `proc/` is `proc` in my project folder(fake root file system `~/workspace/apollo.0`). `ls /proc` is understood.

**Case 2:** **By not exiting** from `chroot`, ran below commands,

```
    overexchange@ab111@~/workspace/apollo.0>mountpoint /proc; printf "$?\n"
    /proc is a mountpoint
    0
    overexchange@ab111@~/workspace/apollo.0>mountpoint proc/; printf "$?\n"
    proc/ is not a mountpoint
    1
    overexchange@ab111@~/workspace/apollo.0>
```

Being in `chroot`, don't be confused by prompt showing my folder path rather than `%`, because this part is customized.

---

Being in `chroot`, below is the info

```
overexchange@ab111@~/workspace/apollo.0>mount
/dev/md125 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=writeback)
none on /dev type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /var/run/netns type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
/dev/md125 on /home/abcdef type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=writeback)
/dev/md125 on /home/overexchange type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=writeback)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
/dev/md125 on /tmp/.X11-unix type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=writeback)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)

overexchange@ab111@~/workspace/apollo.0>cat /proc/mounts
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
/dev/md125 / ext4 rw,relatime,data=writeback 0 0
none /dev tmpfs rw,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /var/run/netns tmpfs rw,relatime 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
/dev/md125 /home/abcdef ext4 rw,relatime,data=writeback 0 0
/dev/md125 /home/overexchange ext4 rw,relatime,data=writeback 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
/dev/md125 /tmp/.X11-unix ext4 rw,relatime,data=writeback 0 0
tmpfs /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/memory cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/devices cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio 0 0
overexchange@ab111@~/workspace/apollo.0>
```

---

Taking second case, I could not understand two points,

1) `/proc` and `proc/` both are `~/workspace/apollo.0` but `/proc` is shown as mount point unlike `proc/`.

2) `ls /proc` shows the process details, but `ls proc` does not show the process details.

How do I understand this?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Clearly `/proc` is `/proc` while `proc/` is `/home/overexchange/workspace/apollo.0/proc`. Why do you expect them to be the same?

Comment: Because `proc` dose not start with a `/` it is a relative path. That is relative to the current working directory.

Comment: @richard Yes, **If I exit** from `chroot` then, `/proc` is `proc` in actual root file system. `proc/` is `proc` in my project folder(fake root file system). **If I do not exit** from `chroot` then my understanding is both `/proc`  and `proc/`  are `~/workspace/appollo.0/proc`, my project folder.

Comment: Only the processes inside the chroot (so the process that did the chroot and the processes it forks) see it. The other processes are not affected. If you're able to see the `~/workspace/apollo.0` folder, you're outside the chroot.

Comment: How did you start the chroot?  Did you or your script mount `/proc` (possibly using `mount -t proc proc proc/`)?  What do `mount` and `cat /proc/mounts` show?

Comment: @Mikel Updated query. Yes we use a wrapper of `chroot`, which does mount. But how linux `chroot` work?

Comment: @overexchange Please include what `mount` commands you (or the script) runs in your question.  I would expect `mountpoint proc/` *outside* the chroot to print `proc/ is a mountpoint`.